# Bivariate Distrubution (Uniform) (Probability/Geometry)

Tags: probability

Let T1 and T2 be random times for a company to complete two steps in a certain process. Say T1 and T2 are measured in days and they have the joint p.d.f. that is uniform over the space $1 < t_1 < 10$, $2 < t_2 < 6$, $t_1 + 2t_2 < 14$. What is the $P( T_1 + T_2 > 10)?$

I got $1/18$, but I don't know the correct answer, would just like confirmation if correct. Below I mentioned my method, but as I said, I'm not sure how to draw a picture on here.

Comment: Show in your question how you got to $\frac{1}{18}$.

Comment: I would, but I am not sure how to create a graph on here. I found the region that fit within the listed constraints (which was a triangle) and then I calculated the area of the triangle and multiplied by the value of the joint pdf for a uniform dist.

Answer (score 0):

The answer is $\frac{1}{10}$

Hint: 
The probability of the event is the $\frac{\text{total area for event}}{\text{total area for space}}$

Try again and I will show you the steps in case you cannot solve it.

Comment: my reaction to reading this answer: https://xkcd.com/979/